# Javascript for loop get key and push

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, key, javascript-objects

I have a code like below. Basically if the key is any of these, i will push it to $scope.mykey

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) { 
   var allKeys = Object.keys(response.data[i])
   for (var k = 0; k < allKeys.length; k++) {
     if (allKeys[k] == "ABC" ||
         allKeys[k] == "EFG" ||
         allKeys[k] == "HIG" ||
         allKeys[k] == "KAY" ||
         allKeys[k] == "LOP" ||
         allKeys[k] == "LLP" ||
         allKeys[k] == "JYP" ||
         allKeys[k] == "TWC" ||
         allKeys[k] == "ZHG" ||
         allKeys[k] == "LMD" ||
         allKeys[k] == "PKL" ||
         allKeys[k] == "JIB" ||
         allKeys[k] == "MHT") {
          $scope.mykey.push({
            name: allKeys[k],
            checked: response.data[i].allKeys[k]
          });
        }
      }
```

However, I am getting the error

```
"Cannot read property '7' of undefined
```

I think it has something to do with the `name:` and `checked:`. Whereby for example should be something like this:

```
response.data[i].TWC
```

But now I think it is getting as:

```
 response.data[i].allKeys[7]
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: post the `response.data`

Comment: Can you add a minimal sample data for the response which you use in your code?

Comment: use `indexOf()` instead of multiple `||`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because `response.data[i]` doesn't have property `allKeys`. 
 If you want accessing property with key stored in `allKeys[k]` as string, use:

```
response.data[i][allKeys[k]]
```

As a sidenote, I'd advise using `forEach` loops to improve readability:

```
 response.data.forEach(function(data) {
     var allKeys = Object.keys(data);
     allKeys.forEach(function(key){
         if (key == "ABC" || key == "EFG" || /*...*/ ) {
             $scope.mykey.push({ name: key, checked: data[key] });
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
response.data.map((allKeys)=> {
  let acceptedKeys = ["ABC","EFG","HIG","KAY", "LOP"];
  allKeys.forEach((key, index, allKeys)=>{
    if(acceptedKeys.includes(key)){
      $scope.mykey.push({
        name: key,
        checked: key
      });
    }
  })
})
```